# Can not display drupal console and phpmyadmin on local host at same time

Tags: mysql, drupal, phpmyadmin

I am absolute beginner on Drupal, and nearly that on setting up localhost on my Mac along with MySql. My problem is I can't display Drupal and run phpmyadmin on separate tabs in my browser at the same time. I found that changing the 'AllowOverride' parm in my http.conf file will allow one or the other to work, but not both at the same time.

So in etc/apache2/httpd.conf  `<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">`  section:

If use 'AllowOverride None'
 
  Can get to http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php
  Cannot get to http://localhost/user/login  (get 'The requested URL /user/login was not found on this server')

If use 'AllowOverride All'
 
  Can not get to http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php  (get 'You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.')
 
  Can get to http://localhost/user/login

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd look at your error logs more closely regarding the permission error.

Answer (score 0):

AllowOverride should be set to "All" since that way you are allowing .htaccess file to work properly (i.e. do redirections and make pretty urls work).

If phpMyAdmin is not working with that setup that means that Drupal's .htaccess rules are catching your requests to phpMyAdmin. That probably means that you installed Drupal directly inside web root and phpMyAdmin inside it's one directory (as a sub-site of Drupal). So even you are calling phpMyAdmin Drupal jumps in and takes control of that request.

One solution would be to install Drupal inside it's own directory, so you could access your project as i.e.

http://localhost/drupal

That way Drupal's .htaccess file will be inside drupal dir and not in web root dir.

Other solution would be to create virtual hosts, so depending on used domain web server would know which site to display (to serve request from which directory).

Comment: Thought your solution worked for a minute. Drupal was in root directory and phpmyadmin was in subdirectory off that. So moved drupal to it's own directory. ( So now have root/drupal and root/phpmyadmin) per your suggestion. Now can get to phpmyadmin and localhost/drupal/user/login. But if I click on say 'Content' in Drupal to create content  the url that pops up is localhost/admin/content (not localhost/drupal/...) and get a Not Found.  How do I tell Drupal that it needs to include 'drupal' in the urls?